# How to make sure this order is retained

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I want to make know what's the best way to make sure this order is retained, I think  the best thing will be to apply a function that operates on this on the fly, while sqlite retains the order, postgres doesn't it reorders it when it's saved to the database,

```
list_of_dicts = [[{'id': '3', 'text': ' Perpetual ', 'score': 3}, {'id': '2', 'text': ' Peter Parker ', 'score': 2}, {'id': '1', 'text': ' Miles .T Morales ', 'score': 1}], [{'id': '3', 'text': 'Perpetual ', 'score': 3}, {'id': '1', 'text': 'Miles .T Morales ', 'score': 2}, {'id': '2', 'text': 'Peter Parker ', 'score': 1}], [{'id': '1', 'text': 'Miles .T Morales ', 'score': 3}, {'id': '3', 'text': 'Perpetual ', 'score': 2}, {'id': '2', 'text': 'Peter Parker ', 'score': 1}], [{'id': '3', 'text': ' Perpetual ', 'score': 3}, {'id': '2', 'text': ' Peter Parker ', 'score': 2}, {'id': '1', 'text': ' Miles .T Morales ', 'score': 1}], [{'id': '1', 'text': ' Miles .T Morales ', 'score': 3}, {'id': '2', 'text': ' Peter Parker ', 'score': 2}, {'id': '3', 'text': ' Perpetual ', 'score': 1}], [{'id': '2', 'text': ' Peter Parker ', 'score': 3}, {'id': '3', 'text': ' Perpetual ', 'score': 2}, {'id': '1', 'text': ' Miles .T Morales ', 'score': 1}]]
```

I want to sort the list from highest score to smallest score, but without dependent on the database,

## EDIT

Im using django models.JSONField to store the data. adding queryset.order_by('data__score') has no effect on it when I pull it out to my view.
same thing with models.Meta ordering attribute

```
.....
class Meta:
    ordering = ("data__score",)
```

has no effect, I think this has to do with the database, now I just want to know how to sort this using python instead of relying on database/ORM inconsistency.

## EDIT 2

My model:

```
class Ballot(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    election = models.ForeignKey(
        Election, related_name="ballots", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    data = models.JSONField(null=True)
    cast_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: The best way is modify your query when you read the data from the database to get the results sorted by score. Does not matter in what order you stored the data

Comment: Query sets have an [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) method. If you don't specify an order the data will be returned in an arbitrary order from any relational database and that order might or might not be want you want.

Comment: I left somethng important out from my question. its using the django JSONField()

Comment: [This](https://riptutorial.com/django/example/16783/ordering-by-jsonfield-values) migth be helpful

Comment: This doesn't order the qs. @RustamGarayev

Comment: You seem to store some sort of _relationhip_ (They have ids and everything) in that `JSONField`? A relationship should be expressed via _foreign keys_ and multiple tables / entities, you face the problem you do because of a bad database schema / design.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Not entirely, without having to create more table for something as simple just ordering by max score, I dumped the result which was generated from the frontend javascript to the `JSONField`, I just need to iterate over it and in sorted order and feed the to a script I was using, `pyrankvote`. I thought that was one the main use cases of `JSONField`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this question by python sort and function attribute.

```
model_ballot = ModelBallot.objects.filter(
    election__id__exact=election_id
).values_list("data", flat=True)

new_model_ballot = []
ballots = list()
for b in model_ballot:
    newlist = sorted(b, key=lambda k: k['score'], reverse=True)
    new_model_ballot.append(newlist)
```

Comment: While this answer gets the correct output, it is incredibly inefficient. You should learn about the `order_by()` method which will do the sorting at the database level.

Comment: I also suggest you look at the difference when you do just `filter()` without `values_list()`. This will allow you to use model objects directly rather than dictionaries, which can often lead to cleaner code since you can do `ballot.score` rather than `ballot["score"]`.

Comment: `data` is a json field, `order_by` doesn't work on it,